# List files which are new or deleted between two branches

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

I've two branches in perforce. Branch12.0 and Branch14.0. How can I find files which are deleted/added from Branch14.0 since Branch12.0?

Comment: If you don't want to write that script, P4V has a very nice visual "Diff Files Or Folders" tool that makes it easy to view the differences between the two branches.

Comment: Thanks for the info Bryan. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `p4 diff2` ([help](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/index.html#p4_diff2.html)):

```
p4 diff2 -q //depot/Branch12.0/... //depot/Branch14.0/...
```

Each line of the output will look like this:

```
==== file1 - file2 ==== summary
```

where *file1* and *file2* are either depot paths with revisions, or `<none>`. For files which are missing in one branch, *summary* will be empty:

```
p4 diff2 -q //depot/Branch12.0/... //depot/Branch14.0/... | grep '=$'
```

This gives you results like:

```
==== //depot/Branch12.0/file.txt#1 - <none> ====
==== <none> - //depot/Branch14.0/file2.txt#1 ====
```

indicating that `file.txt` that was deleted in Branch14.0, and `file2.txt` was added.